# Modification of alternate index values in a 2D array - Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list ->
`m = [13, 8, 2, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8]`.
I am trying to calculate `result = m%4` and place it in a 2D array at alternating positions (described by -1).

```
[[-1. 3. -1. 1.]
 [3. -1. 2. -1.]
 [-1. 1. -1. 0.]
 [3. -1. 1. -1.]]
```

I tried calculating the parity of the indexes (-1 occupies all indexes of odd parity) and placing the result there using a for loop but it just ends up replacing all the -1 with the result after each loop.

I want it to calculate the result for the first list item and then add it to the first '-1' position and then do the the same for the next result but this time adding it to the next '-1' and so on.

Any and all insights are appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Don't you just want `a[a==-1] = m`?

Comment: It is unclear how you construct your array. Could you please elaborate on it? Thank you

Comment: @user3483203, you're right but what that does is substitute all '-1' values with a specific 'm' value (here 13%4) due to which further 'm' values from the list are never added to the 2D array.

Comment: @Ehsan  I just place '-1' at every index which satisfies the following condition - `((i%2 == 0 and j%2 == 0) or (i%2 != 0 and j%2 != 0)) `

Comment: @HammadMansoor that's not correct.  It will fill in each sequential number.  Did you even try what I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your 2D list is

```
a = [[-1,0],[0,-1]]
```

A way to select all the -1 and replace the items would be:

```
m_index = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[-1])):
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
            a[i][j] = m[m_index]%4
            m_index += 1
```

I believe this is not the most pythonic way to do the task, but it's the best that popped into my mind.
Remember to be sure that `len(m)` matches with the number of -1s.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I was trying to parse the 'm' list using a for loop which was creating issues, this solves everything.